# Segfault in trying to access "removed" object property

Tags: segmentation-fault, php

I am running into PHP segfaults on a particular machine, I have tested 3 other machines and all seems to work, but the bug seems closely related to PHP I wanted to share it here.

My script (though much more complicated) is like this.

```
WP_Query->post // StdClass

// some stuff happens

// Try to access WP_Query->post here causes a segfault

get_userdate( 3 );

// WP_Query->post is now inexplicably populated with a WP_User object, 
// though get_userdata does not reference it in any way
```

The "some stuff happens" is actually an apparently unrelated function call, which folows this pattern

```
function a() {
    // WP_Query->post is correct
    // function body
    // WP_Query->post is correct
    return true;
}

// WP_Query->post is correct
a();
// accessing WP_Query->post causes a segfault
```

It's like the garbage collection is removing the memory for the object somehow, though I tried calling "gc_disable()" and that didn't fix anything.

PHP Version: PHP 5.3.6-13ubuntu3.9 with Suhosin-Patch (cli) (built: Sep 12 2012 19:00:27) 
FPM: PHP 5.3.6-13ubuntu3.9 (fpm-fcgi) (built: Sep 12 2012 19:04:27)

I have tried disable PHP extensions (memcached, apc) to no avail.

I tried to a gdb backtrace, the error seems to come form `zend_std_read_property (object=0x1)` though I couldn't really get much more info than that, I think because PHP was not compiled with 'debug'.

Any advice here would be much appreacited, been banging my head against this for about 12 hours so far!

Comment: I think we'll probably need to see more code. Most common cause of PHP segfaults is infinite loops and recursive function calls, might be worth seeing if `WP_Query->post` is in danger of either of those conditions. You might also consider upgrading your PHP version - 5.3.6 is pretty old.

Comment: Thanks @DaveRandom, totally understand about the code, the codebase is very large and also not-public so I tried to illustrate the problem, though it would appear it certainly didn't trigger "ahh, similar thing happened to me" response. I think I will try get the sysops to upgrade PHP, unfortunately it's running 11.10so not sure if 5.3.10 will be in their sources list!